# Update rows with previous rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, subquery

I have a table with a column 'id' which is autoincrement. In some  records i have zero values. I want to update them by their previous rows (here previous means id - 1) .
How can i do that?

This query returns those records with zero values:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE col1 = 0
```

which returns:

```
id  col1  col2  ..... coln
15   0     0           0
23   0     0           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery:

```
update mytable t
set col1 = (select t1.col1 from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id - 1)
where col1 = 0
```